# Magento 1.9.1 - Images not uploading, Destination folder is not writable or does not exists

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, image-uploading, centos7

I am trying to fix an issue where images are not uploading to the site via Magento's admin interface. The error I get is "**/var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/media/slide/slides/Destination folder is not writable or does not exists**". I have done the following:

- Set recursive 777 permissions to slide, slide & slides, slides (in that order, one at a time)
- Change ownership from regular user to apache, then back to regular user if apache user didn't work
- Set media folder permissions to 777
- Set media folder ownership to apache, then back to regular user if it didn't work
- Delete the slide folder and let the uploader create the folders, but gives the error "Unable to create directory '**/var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/media/slide/slides**'

I'm not sure what else to try.

**System Info:**

```
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

NAME="CentOS Linux"

VERSION="7 (Core)"

ID="centos"

ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"

VERSION_ID="7"

PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"

ANSI_COLOR="0;31"

CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"

HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"


CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"

REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"

REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)

**PHP Version:** 5.4.16 

**HTTPD Version:** 2.4.6

**MariaDB Version:** 15.1 Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1



**SELinux Status:**

SELinux status:                 enabled

SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux

SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux

Loaded policy name:             targeted

Current mode:                   enforcing

Mode from config file:          enforcing

Policy MLS status:              enabled

Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
```

**EDIT**

I ran the command `getfacl media` and got the following output:

```
# file: media
# owner: tmweb
# group: tmweb
user::rwx
user:tmweb:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::rwx
```

Do I need to set a group to the folder? If so, what command do I use to grant the group write access?

I have tried `chgrp -R tmweb media` and `chown -R tmweb:tmweb media` but no change.

**EDIT 2**

I have run `getfacl slide` and got the following output:

```
[root@host-tm-web media]# getfacl slide/
# file: slide/
# owner: tmweb
# group: tmweb
user::rwx
user:tmweb:rwx
group::rwx
group:tmweb:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue. It is because the server is running SELinux, so I had to apply additional permissions. For those that face this issue, this is what I have done:

Find out the user for your website

```
<?php
echo `whoami`;
?>
```

Run the following commands in terminal within the root directory:

```
chown -R apache:apache media

find media -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

find media -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t media -R

chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t media -R
```

Thank you to the people that provided answers, you have helped me find the solution to the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Make you sure that you have set 777 permission recursively and folder group and owner should have access to write permission.

you can use below command to change owner and group.

```
sudo chown [user]:[group] folder_name
```

Comment: I already have root access and have been running the following commands:

   chown -R apache:apache slide
   chown -R user:user slide

Comment: yes this is fine but make sure that group has web write permission.

Comment: Please see the edits in my question. I have specified the permissions on the media and slide folder. I am now having problems with uploading images in general, for example, I cannot upload images for products.

Comment: Product image store in `/media/catalog/product`  so please give all permission to media folder and user and group also. i hope you know `chmod` and `chown` command properly because in both the command user and group include so

Answer (score 0):

Please Clean cache and restart apache server also make sure mod_rewrite is enable

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled and I have cleared the cache. Issue still not resolved.

Comment: Do onething just create  folder in side media/slide/slides and then try to upload image from admin and yes set the permission to 777

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and still giving the same error.